# injective sequence of natural numbers has infinite plus limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, natural-numbers

**Question**

Injective sequence of natural numbers $(a_n)$ has $\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=+\infty$.

**Draft**

I thought, if it's injective, like $\mathbb N$ is not majored, it's not bounded, so it doesn't converge. Then, if it doesn't converge, one of the two, either the limit is plus infinite or it doesn't exist. But how do you prove it doesn't exist?

Comment: Consider $(-1)^nn$.

Comment: @IgnacioHenríquez: But the sequence is $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, isn't it?

Comment: But this is not $(a_n) \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: @BrianTung yes .

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, my mistake.

Comment: The definition of $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \infty$ is that for any $M$ there is an $N_M$ so that for all $n > N_M$ we have $a_n > M$.  Now $M$ is finite and $a_k$ is injective so there are only finite number of $a_k$ where $a_k < M$ (there are at most $M$ of them) and infinitely many where $a_k> M$.  Muck around with the wording a bit and eventually Martin R's solution will have to jump out and grab you by the throat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $R > 0$ there are only finitely many indices $n$ with $a_n \le R$, since $(a_n)$ is injective. So we can define
$$
 N(R) = \max \{ n \mid a_n \le R \} \, .
$$

Then for all $R > 0$, $n > N(R) \implies a_n > R$, and that proves $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = +\infty$.